# Textarea return .val() only if more than 15 chars

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

can you tell me why with this form:

```
<div id="comment-form">
<h3>Commenta questo racconto:</h3>
<form method="post" id="story-comment-form" action="#">
    <textarea name="comment" id="story-comment-text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="vote" class="submit" id="story-comment-submit" title="Invia commento" value="Invia commento"/>
<form>
</div>
```

and this jquery code:

```
$("#story-comment-submit").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $("#story-comment-text").val();
    alert(a);
});
```

var a returns a value only if there are more than 15chars in the form textarea?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/malet/St2FX/ - it seems to be working fine, have you got any other bits of code which may be interfering?

Comment: [Negative](http://jsfiddle.net/JmPUS/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SE2Nq/ Tried it in IE, Chrome, Firefox. Works with less and more than 15 characters.

Comment: this is all the of the form, i don't know how to make it work in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cPf7S/

Comment: You haven't set the right jQuery library on the right, but even when u do, it works for me although there are about 5 space characters in the textarea because of your HTML is laid out.

Comment: @AntonioCiccia - Then you should either post the answer yourself and mark it as accepted so others can see it, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, i had a problem with another script. Sorry guys.